# I want to learn Esperanto in a presence-course format. Where can I participate in an actual course like this?

Tags: learning, course

I live in Europe, in Germany. I know about NASK, but maybe there is something in Europe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I have seen, all over the world, and especially all over Europe, there are classroom courses in most regions. They are typically offered by Esperanto clubs or in adult education centres (in Germany: Volkshochschulen). Most universities also have course catalogues similar to adult education centres, were you might also find Esperanto courses.

Answer (score 2):

Since asking this question I have registered on [edukado.net](http://edukado.net/novajhoj?id=659) and have started receiving their newsletters. 
In the newsletter there is a section on presence-courses around the world.
For anyone looking on up to date information on Esperanto courses, that is a recommendation!

The event Limbas (Sardinian for languages), a multilingual event where Esperanto is also taught, is going to take place in Sardinia 2017 (as far as I know). Last year it looked [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQbjwIRs3dw&t=3s).